# Why does Eslint report different results on different machines?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, tslint

In our project we were using tslint but recently migrated to eslint. Running the command `"eslint \"packages/**/*.{ts,tsx}\""` on my local machine (Windows) reports 1 error and 409 warnings but running the same command on a linux machine reports 1 error and 2746 warnings.

The result of running linter with --env-info flag is same on both machines

```
Node version: v12.16.1
npm version: v6.13.4
Local ESLint version: v7.22.0 (Currently used)
Global ESLint version: Not found
```

The version of the plugins also seems to match.

The folder structure looks like this:

```
.eslintrc.js
tsconfig.json
package.json
.eslintignore
packages/ (contains subprojects which don't have their own eslint config files)
```

The contents of the configuration files:

.eslintrc.js file

```
module.exports = {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "project": "./tsconfig.json",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "eslint-plugin-jsdoc",
        "eslint-plugin-import",
        "eslint-plugin-react",
        "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow",
        "react-hooks",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "version": "17.0.0",
        },
    },
    "rules": {...}
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.md",
    "**/dist/**"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

I also checked out some of the warnings that the Linux machine reported but my local Windows machine didn't. For example the following rows both report a warning "Unsafe call of an any typed value"

```
const {breakPoints} = useTheme();
const currentBreak = useCurrentBreakPoint(breakPoints);
```

but the types do seem to be correct and typescript is not complaining about them either.

What might be causing the differences in linting results between the two machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by missing dependencies. Running "npm install" in all of the subprojects before linting fixed the problem.